# nodejs/expressjs update(crUd) operation is not displaying css files

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I am making a CRUD app in Nodejs/Expressjs, templating engine is EJS.

The idea for the update is display user_id from a database and when admin clicks on user_id it should redirect to edit_team.ejs page.

It is working fine but when it is redirecting to edit_team.ejs page, the css files are not getting load. I am getting below error
[image]

For every other .ejs files, all css files are loaded.

I have included 'public' folder in app.js file.

Code:

Folder Directory:

[image]

app.js:

```
app.use(express.static('app/public'));
```

view_team.ejs

```
<a class="button" href='/edit_team/<%= team[i].team_id %>'>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

edit_team.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
const { Client } = require('pg')
const connectionString = 'postgresql://localhost:5432/idid';

//router object
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/edit_team/:id', function(req, res){
 res.render('login/edit_team');
});

module.exports = router;
```

edit_team.ejs (pasting only head section):

```
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>

 </title>
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
  awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

can someone please help me trying to figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: Please post your server.js or app.js... or whichever file you use as startup.  It "looks" like it could be that you don't have express serving your css files as static content, but i could be wrong here due to lack of information.

Comment: Added. But all other templating files, are running properly. I think I am not handing properly "edit" operation in nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL such as `/edit_team/23` serves up `edit_team.ejs`, which contains the relative path `css/bootstrap.min.css`. This is relative to the `/edit_team` path, so it'll be `edit_team/css/bootstrap.min.css`, which probably isn't what you want.

You should be able to confirm this using your browser's dev tools. Look in the Network tab and check the paths for the files that aren't loading.

Try using paths that aren't relative to the current path, such as:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note the extra `/`.

Comment: You are a genius! I was trying to solve this issue since yesterday. the relative and absolute path are important and now I understand it's value. THANKS a lot.